# Sticky Bootstrap Footer in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**Solved**. I use this solution: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

===

I'm creating a [social media share count app](http://prospekdigital.com/social-signal-checker/) using AngularJS. User need to enter an URL and hit the "*Kira*" button before the data appears.

The data will appear with other items like screenshots and some text below it.

I try to make my footer sticky but it's not working in mobile view.

Desktop view:

[image]

Mobile view:

[image]

This is my `index.html` for the footer part:

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="panel-footer text-center">
            <p class="tcenter"><small>Dibangunkan oleh <a href="http://facebook.com/handyplast" target="_blank">Zulhilmi Zainudin</a> // Teh tarik ditaja oleh <a href="http://www.binablogdotcomsendiri.com/blog/?utm_source=social-signal-checker&utm_medium=social-signal-checker-tool&utm_campaign=social-signal-checker" target="_blank">Bina Blog Dot Com Sendiri</a> &#128522;</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my `style.css` file for the footer part:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */

    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**My question**:
How to make the footer sticky in both view (desktop and mobile)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do

Markup

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

As mentioned in my comment you need to use `Media-Query` change on style on smaller screen.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.footer {
    //Mobile footer style here
}
}
```

read more about `Media-Queries` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Comment: In your mobile view you need to use `Media-Queries`. Which you can tailor to different screen sizes.

Comment: Could you please share example for this context?

Comment: Heads up, Bootstrap is 'mobile first', so you should style it how you would like to see it on a mobile in your styles normally, and then use a media query to adjust the style for tablet/desktop.